# Push response through Apigee

Tags: apigee

We plan to have a REST API exposed by Apigee Edge. The client-facing endpoints will be managed by Apigee. Another REST service will be hosted behind the Apigee. When the Apigee endpoint is invoked, we plan to store the request in Kafka so that it can be processed asynchronously. After the server has processed it, we intend to Push a message to the client application that made the request.

Is this a common practice?

Does Apigee have a feature to remember the client such as its websocket so that the notification can be pushed?

Comment: Do you want to return to the client right after sending the message to Kafka? I mean don't you want to wait until your underlying Rest service hosted behind Apigee process your request? And you intended to send a message to Kafka from Apigee?

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, Apigee is a Gateway for synchroneous APIs. There is no default way to do "come back" to a request that has been processed earlier. So: No, this is not common practice.

A more common practice would be to add an asynchroneous callout to "another REST service behind Apigee", meaning that Apigee returns a response immediately without waiting for the target to complete. That backend service would then implement the callback on its own, possibly via some other Apigee proxy.

In your specific case, the pattern you're implementing is basically a message queue, utilizing Kafka as the message broker. In such patterns, it's best practice to have the message receiver send a reply message as soon as it finished its work.

Regarding websockets, Apigee doesn't support it at the moment (see https://community.apigee.com/questions/60513/apigee-as-websocket-proxy.html).